# C - puts() vs. printf() using \b

Tags: c, printf, puts

```
printf("backspace\b");
```

Output: backspac

```
puts("backspace\b");
```

Output: backspace

Why is this? Because `puts()` adds a terminating newline character and `\b` is therefore without effect?

Comment: The `\b` only moves the cursor one character to the left, it typically does not erase a character. Thus the effect of this depends on what you output next. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 puts("Hello world\b");
 printf("Hello world\b");
 return 0;
}

Comment: What if you `printf("Hello world\b\n");`?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 printf("Hello world\b\n");
 return 0;
} results in "Hello world".

Comment: And what happens when you `puts("Hello world\b ")`? Note the final space. Backspace is sometimes *non-destructive* until you print another char.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 printf("Hello world\b ");
 return 0;
}  results in "Hello worl ".

Comment: `puts("Hello world\b \b")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("backspace\b");
```

On a typical terminal or emulator, this will print the string `backspace` and then move the cursor back one position, leaving it on top of the final `e`.  If you're seeing `backspac`, it's because something else clobbered the `e` after the `printf` call, either because the same program prints more output (which you haven't shown us) or because something happened after the program finished.  If that `printf` is the only statement in your program and you're running in a Unix-like shell, then the shell prompt is likely to clobber the `e`.

```
puts("backspace\b");
```

The `puts` function appends a newline `'\n'` to its output.  This is equivalent to

```
printf("backspace\b\n");
```

As with the previous example, the `\b` will cause the cursor to move back one position, on top of the `e`, but then then `\n'` causes it to move to the beginning of the next line, which doesn't clobber the `e`.

In both cases, the backspace character `'\b'` is written to stdout. If you run your program with output redirected to a file and then examine the file, you'll see it, perhaps shown as `^H` or as `08` in hexadecimal, depending on how you view it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they both move cursor one place back, but puts() appends a newline in the end of the word, so if you try to overwrite the current cursor you don't actually erase the 'e', because the cursor has already dropped to the next line.

Like someone said in the comments, a code example would give a more precise and correct answer.

EDIT: Judging by the comments, it appears like moving the cursor back and then printing a char will overwrite the word, unless that char is a newline, which will not.

```
printf("backspace\b\n "); // Output: backspace

printf("backspace\b"); // Output: backspac|e (| for cursor)

printf("backspace\b "); // Output: backspac
```

Comment: But the output of printf("backspace\b"); is not backspac|e (| for cursor) but backspac.

Comment: @Andreas And what is after "backspac"? Your prompt, which has overriden the 'e'?